# I open a shortcut when shortcut don't exist , why not show this dialog?

Tags: delphi, winapi, shortcut

I use `ShellExecute` to open a shortcut

Code :

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'C:\Users\hi2012\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\xxx.gif.lnk', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

if **xxx.gif** exist that code can open it , if not it don't give anything.

but , when I open it with windows explorer it will show this:

[image]

I want when I use code to open a not nonexistent shortcut it also can show that , what can I do ?

is this a wrong way to use `ShellExecute` to open a shortcut ?

Comment: @TobiasR That's how to invoke `Open With` dialog.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan uups - as you mention it... true.

Answer (score 3):

[`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) doesn't show dialogs when it fails. And it will not offer to delete files on your behalf. That dialog is shown by the `Explorer` app.

In order to handle errors you need to check the return value of the call to `ShellExecute`. If that return value is greater than 32 then the call succeeded. Otherwise there was an error. The possible reported errors are listed in the documentation.

For better error handling, use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx). If a call to `ShellExecuteEx` fails then you can obtain an error code by calling `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`IShellLink::Resolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774952.aspx) to resolve the shortcut yourself. `IShellLink::Resolve` offers flags to control whether to show search UI.

Comment: I try my best to do that , but it doesn't work , could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: @ONion: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891.aspx#Shellink_Resolving_Shortcut for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can [invoke "open" from context popup menu on .lnk file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/30/236133.aspx). This will give you the same behaviour as double-clicking .lnk file in Explorer:

```
function SHBindToParent(pidl: PItemIDList; const riid: TIID; out ppv; out ppidlLast: PItemIDList): HResult; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll' name 'SHBindToParent';

procedure ExecuteFile(const AWnd: HWND; const AFileName: String);

  function GetUIObjectOfFile(wnd: HWND; const pszPath: WideString; const riid: TGUID; out ppv): HRESULT;
  var
    pidl: PItemIDList;
    sfgao: DWord;
    psf: IShellFolder;
    pidlChild: PItemIDList;
  begin
    DWord(ppv) := 0;
    Result := SHParseDisplayName(PWideChar(pszPath), nil, pidl, 0, sfgao);
    if SUCCEEDED(Result) then
    try
      Result := SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, psf, pidlChild);
      if SUCCEEDED(Result) then
      try
        Result := psf.GetUIObjectOf(wnd, 1, pidlChild, riid, nil, ppv);
      finally
        psf := nil;
      end;
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
    end;
  end;

const
  SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST = 1;
  SCRATCH_QCM_LAST  = $7FFF;
var
  pcm: IContextMenu;
  Menu: HMENU;
  Info: TCMInvokeCommandInfo;
  Id: UINT;
begin
  if SUCCEEDED(GetUIObjectOfFile(AWnd, PChar(AFileName), IID_IContextMenu, pcm)) then
  try
    Menu := CreatePopupMenu;
    if Menu <> 0 then
    try
      if SUCCEEDED(pcm.QueryContextMenu(Menu, 0, SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST, SCRATCH_QCM_LAST, CMF_DEFAULTONLY)) then
      begin
        Id := GetMenuDefaultItem(Menu, 0, 0);
        if Id <> UINT(-1) then
        begin
          FillChar(Info, SizeOf(Info), 0);
          Info.cbSize := SizeOf(info);
          Info.hwnd := Handle;
          Info.lpVerb := MAKEINTRESOURCEA(Id - SCRATCH_QCM_FIRST);
          SetLastError(pcm.InvokeCommand(Info));
          if GetLastError <> 0 then
            RaiseLastOSError;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      DestroyMenu(Menu);
    end;
  finally
    pcm := nil;
  end;
end;
```

The same should be archieved by calling ShellExecuteEx with SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST flag.